# Matplotlib Axes Offset

Tags: matplotlib

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to rotate the axes for two overlayed plots. When I set the rotation to vertical then it lines up with the correct columns but when I rotate the x-axes then they become offset.

Here is my code:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.bar(range(1, 24, 3), gender_factors[1:2][[i for i in range(8)]].values.T, tick_label=traits_8, align = 'center', color = '#00cccc', label='Men')
ax.bar(range(0, 24, 3), gender_factors[2:3][[i for i in range(8)]].values.T, tick_label=traits_8, align = 'center', color = '#990033', label='Women')

plt.title('Personality Traits by Gender')

ax.set_xticklabels(traits_8, rotation=60) 

plt.xticks(range(0, 24, 3), traits_8, rotation='vertical')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can I fix the offset-ness? I've tried playing with range(0,24,3) to get it right but it isn't working.

[image: vertical]
[image: 45-degrees]

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. If you look closely at the bottom plot, the *center* of the text still lines up with the center of the bars.

To fix this, you can set the horizontal alignment to `'right'` when you create them.

```
plt.xticks(range(0, 24, 3), traits_8, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

[image]